# Bootstrap 3 tooltip with PHP / CodeIgniter

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm adding html to my page via PHP and can't seem to get my bootstrap tooltip image to work to function properly.

```
<li class="list-group-item col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><a href="'.site_url(url_title($artist['firstname'].' '.$artist['lastname']).'-a'.$artist['id']).'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto" data-html="true" title="<img src="'.base_url('image/get/resize/'.IMAGE_RESIZE_AND_CROP.'/width/200/height/150/id/'.$artwork[0]['image_id']).'">">'.$artist['firstname'].' '.strtoupper($artist['lastname']).'</a></li>
```

The problem is located in my tooltip title:

```
title="<img src="'.base_url('image/get/resize/'.IMAGE_RESIZE_AND_CROP.'/width/200/height/150/id/'.$artwork[0]['image_id']).'">"
```

Result: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cts5V.png)

The names appear this way: ">Raymond ABNER and there is nothing in the tooltips. From what I conclude, the problem is possibly in my usage of " and ', but I can't find a workaround (also, not sure about this).

Comment: you are adding base_url inside html. you should use like src = "<?= base_url('') ?>"

Comment: can you post the larger script the foreach eg.

Comment: it's used inside a variable

Comment: ur storing the whole thing in a variable ? and outputing at the end

Comment: yes, in my controller file (CodeIgniter framework) and it parses 'views' webpage file afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer... The " within my src= where the problem. Took them off and it works fine.

Final code segment:

```
<li class="list-group-item col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><a href="'.site_url(url_title($artist['firstname'].' '.$artist['lastname']).'-a'.$artist['id']).'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto" data-html="true" title="<img src='.base_url('image/get/resize/'.IMAGE_RESIZE_AND_CROP.'/width/200/height/150/id/'.$artwork[0]['image_id']).'>">'.$artist['firstname'].' '.strtoupper($artist['lastname']).'</a></li>
```